# Ensuring security of files in folder on public_html

Tags: php, apache, security, directory-structure

I have a directory structure of images in my public_html, like this:

```
public_html/
   design_images/
       product_11/
           112342_234/ ... a bunch of images stored here for this product
           112343_910/ ... images for this product
           more image folders/...
           ...
```

Within the `public_html` folder I have php files that do image processing and PDF conversion in the product folders. I'm just worried that somehow someone might inject some script somewhere and delete one of the product folders. I kept all these directories on public_html because very often throughout the website I need to dynamically display images from the product folders.

How can I secure against this? I'm using Apache on a virtual server, and I have access to root in my hosting package.

I also have javascript files in public_html/js, is it possible for any scoundrel to come and edit them somehow?

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77/apache-server-hardening

Answer (score 1):

Move out of private html folder and make a script like (in pseudo):

loadimage.php

```
<?
$imageName = $_GET['image']
$file = (abstract folder name and file name from $imagename)
$file = (sanatize all variables before passing it to the filesystem)

$sizeAndType = getimagesize($file);
header('Content-Type:'.$sizeAndType['mime']);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

and call with www.example.com/loadimage.php?image=product_1234_something.jpg (or however you choose to build the name.

then it would be even better to write a htaccess with mod_rewrite to sanitize the url so you can just use your old, or an even better url buildup.

However this does not protect you from everything. you still need to make sure the rest of the server does not have serious holes like 777 public folders and more like that.

Comment: I do have a 777 public folder. Is there any way to allow only my own php files to access those folders, while not allowing anyone else to access them?

Comment: No not to let only your files access it. but the real danger is that apache can put files in it. so people can just put files in there and execute. so if you have any public 777 folders, at least shield them off with .htaccess

Comment: I just realized I don't have public 777 folders, they're 755. And the files within those folders are 644. Is that alright?

Comment: yeah that is ok, it gives read and execute rights, but not write

Comment: In this case - I now see that all my image folders are also 755. Is there still a danger of someone deleting these folders and is it still recommended to move these folders out of public_html?

Comment: it ofcourse also depends on the owner. A 755 folder owned by for example apache, is writable from web. I normally always prefer to put only in public what you need in public. some basic images, main php scripts that are called directly, css, etc. But folders with data written to it by php for example i always put outside public. But it is also a choise, some like it in public but protected and others always want it outside even if it is not a security risk, but just to keep it clean and organised.